# How do I modify the document Root of Spring boot2 embedded tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

How do I modify the document root of the built-in tomcat instead of using the "src/main/webapp"

Answer (score 1):

Set the path to your document root as `server.tomcat.document-root` in `application.properties`

```
@Value("${server.tomcat.document-root}")
private String documentRoot;
```

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableWebServerFactory> webServerFactoryCustomizer() {
    return new WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableWebServerFactory>() {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableWebServerFactory factory) {
            if (factory instanceof TomcatServletWebServerFactory) {
                TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = (TomcatServletWebServerFactory) factory;
                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(documentRoot)) {
                    File root = new File(documentRoot);
                    tomcat.setDocumentRoot(root);
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your application.properties, add a property:

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/yourpathgoeshere
```